# jQuery toggle and slide for testimonials setup

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make a custom slider for a few testimonials. The picture below illustrate how it should work. The first testimonial is highlighted and when the user clicks on the next testimonial the yellow background should slide to it, the font color of the name and company should change and also the actual testimonial text should slide.

[image]

I managed to make a functional version, which you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QJ5PQ/) or live on this [website](http://triplemagicinteractive.com/). Any improvements and explanations will be highly appreciated (I'm still very new to jQuery).

Here is the jQuery code I used:

```
$("div.container-slider").click(

function () {
    $("div.active-slide").toggleClass("animate", 1000, function () {
        $("div.mike").toggleClass("current-font", function () {
            $("span").toggleClass("company-current");
        }),
        $("div.neil").toggleClass("inactive-slide", function () {
            $("span").toggleClass("company");
        });
    }),

    $("div.testimonial-text").slideToggle("slow", function () {
        $("div.testimonial-text-2").toggleClass("display-none");
    });
});
```

**Problems:**

1. How can I make the font color and weight change more subtle?
2. How can I target specific `span` codes, because right now the script changes the `span` color everywhere on the website?
3. How can I make the testimonial-text slide more smoothly (similar to the yellow background)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It looks like you're already using CSS transitions. Have you tried fiddling with them?
2. Use `this` to limit scope to the current element, as in `$(this).find('span')....`, or use index (`eq()`) to target by slide, or give the relevant spans a class to target.
3. I'm not sure why you're toggling your display-none class, but that's
   probably causing the abruptness. Try removing that.

Comment: Thanks, I'll use transitions to fix the font changes and `this` to limit the scope. I used the `display-none` class to hide the second testimonial and then while I slide the first one, I show the second one. There's a better way in doing this?

Comment: I'd use `slideToggle` on both elements.